Как запустить sql sqript в pgadmin4 в Linux?
У меня есть скрипт БД demo-small.sql нужно его импортировать в pgadmin4, в WIndows я в командной строке psql вводил \i путь к скрипту, но как в Linux это сделать?
Ввел команды:
1)sudo -u postgres psql
2)\i /home/asl/Загрузки/demo-small-20170815.sql
Пишет:
Отказано в доступе

Т.е. psql на линукс тачке нет? Или что? Синтаксис от win и lin версии принципиально разный? В чём затык? Ты не знаешь путь? Ну так мы тоже не знаем.

@donRumata Привет! Смотрите Я дополнил вопрос. Ввел команды, которые нужны. Мне пишет отказано в доступе.

Ну в /home - да, может не пускать, потому что другой пользователь. Положи куда-нибудь в /var/cache и дай chmod 644 на файл.

попробуйте для запуска консоли psql -U postgres под своим пользователем

@donRumata Спасибо за ответ! А просто перенес свой скрипт в /var/cache и от туда уже его запустил и все сработало! Но почему не сработало в другом пути? И еще как вам рейтинг дать или очко или как это называется

Оформил каменты как ответ, можешь плюсовать.

Проблема в том, что sql-дамп находится в профиле пользователя. Чтобы туда добраться из под другого пользователя - нужно больше магии. Проще на данном этапе - положить файл туда, откуда его смогут читать все. Например - /var/cache. sudo wget или sudo mv в помощь. Дополинтельно, можно дать права, чтобы точно преточно любой залогиненый пользователь мог дамп прочесть: chmod 644 /var/cache/demo-small-20170815.sql.
